# Convox CLI deploy gives 502 response

Tags: convox

I'm suddenly having issues deploying my apps to AWS ECS using the Convox CLI. When I am trying as of Friday, this is what happens:

```
$ convox deploy -a my-app -r test
Packaging source... OK
Uploading source... OK
Starting build... ERROR: response status 502
```

This is regardless of rack, and other operations such as "env" and "logs" seem to work. I don't know how to go about trouble shooting this. Is there some switch I can use to get more debug info from the CLI? I am assuming the "502" is an HTTP error code, but I do not know where it is coming from. I've looked around in AWS, but can not seem to find any errors there (however, is not sure where to look).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing a rack update? There was a new release last week to address some changes AWS made to ECS API call validations. https://github.com/convox/rack/pull/3472

Comment: @BrianGalura Upgrading the rack did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on a rack running a version from 2019. Solved this updating the rack to version 20211019100155 as Brian suggested.

Comment: You can just upvote the correct answer